# How to implement IIR filters in C?

Tags: c, filter, filtering, signal-processing

I'm trying to implement simple IIR (Direct Form I) filters in C.

For high-pass (10 Hz at 256 samples/second) I do this:

```
int Diff = Sample - Previous_Sample;

HP_Output = ((HP_Output + Diff) * 4) / 5;
```

For low-pass (10 Hz @ at 32 samples/second) I do this:

```
int Diff = Sample - LP_Output ;

LP_Output = ((LP_Output + Diff) * 2) / 3;
```

Now I was wondering: are both implementations mathematically correct?

And if I want to change the input sample-rate (or filter frequency), how do I calculate the new factors?

Comment: What is entirely missing from your code is *time*.  The sample rate matters a great deal.  A practical filter uses many samples, not just one.  Use Google to find answers, best query is "iir coefficient calculator".

Comment: @HansPassant I call the function for every sample (at 256 samples per second)

Comment: Not what I meant, you have to store old samples.  Recorded at T-1, T-2, T-3, etc.  You need an array.  This will be very obvious once you read the google hits, you'll have to spend the time.

Comment: @HansPassant I store the filtered samples directly to disk, so I dont have an array with history available, but why is that relevant to the filter? Also, the history is indirectly contained in HP_Output and LP_Output.

Comment: Well, of course you do.  Even your snippet has history, it is *Previous_Sample*.  Just one, you can't get anything better than a 1st order filter.  Entirely trivial to store more of course, a circular buffer makes it efficient.  Very hard to guess at the mental block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The high-pass output is correct for a first order filter implementation.
From [high-pass filter realization on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter#Discrete-time_realization), and given a sampling rate `fs` and filter cutoff frequency `fc`, the required factor `alpha` can be obtained from the relation:
[image]

Which yields:
[image]

In the snippet provided, this results in `alpha ~ 4/5`.

For the first order low-pass filter, your code essentially only outputs the scaled input samples (since `LP_Output + Diff == LP_Output + Sample - LP_Output == Sample`). Instead, I'd expect:

```
LP_Output = LP_Output + Diff * 2 / 3;
```

Now, the factor `alpha` can similarly be obtained from derivations based on [low-pass filter realization on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Discrete-time_realization) to be:
[image]

Again, in the snippet provided, this results in `alpha ~ 2/3`.

Finally, as Hans indicated in comments, for higher order filter implementations you should have a look at IIR filter design tools to derive coefficients.

Comment: I dont really understand your suggestion of changing 'LP_Output = ((LP_Output + Diff) * 2) / 3' to 'LP_Output = LP_Output + Diff * 2 / 3', because it doesnt seem to have any effect on the result? Both lines of codes output the same value?

Comment: `LP_Output + Diff * 2 / 3` is equivalent to `LP_Output + (Diff * 2 / 3)`. For example, if current `LP_Output` is 42, and new input `Sample` is 6, your code would have given `Diff == 6-42 == -36`, then updated `LP_Output == ((42 + -36) * 2)/3 == ((6)*2)/3 == 4`. My version updates `LP_Output` to `LP_Output == 42 + -36*2/3 == 42 + (-24) == 18.